# The selected item in a listbox is null how can i fix that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I am working on a listbox system that allows exercises in a regime to be deleted using a remove method in my controller. Currently when i select an item then click remove it returns an empty list of items and no changes are made to the db

At the moment ive got my code to produce no errors however currently after setting some breakpoints it appears that `item` in `RemoveExercises` is currently null. So i changed the line `RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);` to `RegimeItem item = model.RequestedSelected...` and now i am recieving the error **`'int' does not contain a definition for 'RegimeItemID' and no extension method 'RegimeItemID' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found`**

What i want to happen is the regime item that is selected is removed when the remove button is pressed.

**Controller.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(int id, UserExerciseViewModel vmodel)
    {

        //Session["UserExerciseViewModel"] = userExerciseViewModel;
        User user = db.Users.Find(vmodel.UserID);
        //User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        //vmodel.UserID = user.UserID;
        UserExerciseViewModel model = new UserExerciseViewModel { AvailableExercises = GetAllExercises(), RequestedExercises = ChosenExercises(user, vmodel) };
        Session["UserExerciseViewModel"] = model;
        return View(model);
    }

    //Post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExerciseIndex(UserExerciseViewModel model, string add, string remove, string send, int id, RegimeItem item)
    {
        // model = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        //model.UserID = user.UserID;
        User user = db.Users.Find(model.UserID);
        user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
        UserExerciseViewModel model2 = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        model.RequestedExercises = model2.RequestedExercises;
        model.AvailableExercises = model2.AvailableExercises;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(add))
            AddExercises(model, id);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remove))
            RemoveExercises(model, id);              
        SaveState(model);
        RestoreSavedState(model, user);
        return View(model);
    }

    void SaveState(UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        model.SavedRequested = string.Join(",", model.RequestedExercises.Select(p => p.RegimeItemID.ToString()).ToArray());
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    void RemoveExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
    {
        var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
        {
            RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);
            if (item != null)
            {
                User user = db.Users.Find(id);
                model.RequestedExercises.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    void AddExercises(UserExerciseViewModel model, int id)
    {
        var userExerciseViewModel = (UserExerciseViewModel)(Session["UserExerciseViewModel"]);
        foreach (int selected in model.AvailableSelected)
        {
            if (model.AvailableSelected != null)
            {
                User user = db.Users.Find(id);
                user.RegimeItems.Add(new RegimeItem()
                {
                    RegimeExercise = (this.GetAllExercises().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ExerciseID == selected))
                });
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        //RedirectToAction("ExerciseIndex");
    }

    void RestoreSavedState(UserExerciseViewModel model, User user)
    {
        user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
        //get the previously stored items
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SavedRequested))
        {
            string[] exIds = model.SavedRequested.Split(',');
            var regimeItems = ChosenExercises(user, model).Where(p => exIds.Contains(p.RegimeItemID.ToString()));
            model.RequestedExercises.AddRange(regimeItems);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private List<Exercise> GetAllExercises()
    {
        return db.Exercises.ToList();
    }

    private List<RegimeItem> ChosenExercises(User user, UserExerciseViewModel model)
    {
        return db.Users
     .Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID)
     .SelectMany(u => u.RegimeItems)
     .ToList();
    }
```

**Models(cs)**

```
 public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegimeItem> RegimeItems { get; set; }
        public User()
        {
            this.RegimeItems = new List<RegimeItem>();
        } 
    }
    public class RegimeItem
    {
        public int RegimeItemID { get; set; }
        public Exercise RegimeExercise { get; set; }
    }
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class UserExerciseViewModel
{
    public List<Exercise> AvailableExercises { get; set; }
    public List<RegimeItem> RequestedExercises { get; set; }
    public int? SelectedExercise { get; set; }
    public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
    public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
    public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
}
```

**View.cshtml**(Segment only)

```
      <input type="submit" name="remove"
             id="remove" value="<<" />
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
      @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RequestedSelected, new MultiSelectList(Model.RequestedExercises, "RegimeItemID", "RegimeExercise.Name", Model.RequestedSelected))
  </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that your are attempting to get the `RegimeItemID` property of an `int` value; take a look at the following:

```
public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }
RegimeItem item = model.RequestedSelected.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);
```

You basically tell LINQ to try to use the `.RegimeItemID` of the `int` iterator of the `int[]` array.

If I am not mistaken about your structure, you should change the

```
RegimeItem item = model.RequestedSelected.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);
```

to:

```
RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises[selected];
```

in that loop.

```
foreach (int selected in model.RequestedSelected)
//foreach (var item in new ArrayList(model.RequestedExercises.RegimeItemID))
{
    RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises[selected];
    if (item != null)
    {
        model.RequestedExercises.Remove(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

New information provided: the code in the question is infact the right code, however the problem lies with the RestoreSavedState method which should look more along the lines of:

```
void RestoreSavedState(UserExerciseViewModel model, User user)
{
    user.RegimeItems = model.RequestedExercises;
    //get the previously stored items
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SavedRequested))
    {
        string[] exIds = model.SavedRequested.Split(',');
        var regimeItems = ChosenExercises(user, model).Where(p => exIds.Contains(p.RegimeItemID.ToString()));
        model.RequestedExercises.AddRange(regimeItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however that gave me a : An exception of type `'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: @Nilmag Then I am mistaken on your design. What exactly does `selected` in that loop represent? Is it the `RegimeItemID` of the `RequestedExercises` to remove? If so, then the original query should have done it.

Comment: yes, ive just done a breakpoint there and while `item` is null `selected` is showing the RegimeItemID, which is supposed to be a part of `RequestedExercises`.  RequestedExercises is currently showing a count of 0 and the `RequestedSelected` is showing {int[1]}.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @Nilmag If `RequestedExercises` shows a count of `0` then that is your problem. Your original line is in fact the solution to it, however there are no `RequestedExercises` to delete.

Comment: Even with my original line, the count of `RequestedExercises` is 0 and `RequestedSelected` is showing {int[1]}.

Comment: Its confusing as in the list of `RequestedExercises` there are roughly five in total, so when i select an item from the list should that count be one? or should it represent the entire count of RequestedExercises?

Comment: It should have all five in there, which would mean you should just have to use the first query you had (`RegimeItem item = model.RequestedExercises.FirstOrDefault(i => i.RegimeItemID == selected);` would select just the one that is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77816/discussion-between-nilmag-and-ebrown).

Comment: Hey i got it to save to the session! i cannot thank you enough! You mentioned that Synchronising Session state to db is not that difficult (for you!) Do you know of any decent tutorial or stack questions as i do not really know what i am looking for?  Also do mind if i update your answer with the changes i made to RestoreSaveState?

Comment: @Nilmag Really, the synchronization of the `Session` and the database is just verifying that you update the `model` and call `db.SaveChanges()`.